# dropDatabase return error

Tags: linux, mongodb, server

I am trying to drop a database in mongodb, then I switch to this database using command use test and then run `db.dropDatabase()`, but it gives me an error message:

```
{
....

"errmsg" : "not master"

"codeName" : "NotMaster"

...
}
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

This just means you are not connected to the primary replica node. The command will run if you are on the primary. As mongo changes primary automatically, you may be connected to a secondary replica.